# Counting Booleans for Distinct and Non Distinct ID numbers

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a simple table that looks like the following PNG file from the following join:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableA A 
  JOIN tableB B ON B.Main_SPACE_ID = A.Main_SPACE_ID
```

- Table A contains Guest_ON and User_Controls (last 2 columns) and Table B contains Trigger_ON and DOCX_ON.

*Issue*:

What I am trying to do is count all the True's for each tableB.Subspace_ID and the **DISTINCT** trues for tableA.Main_SPACE_ID.

The problem is that subspace_ID from table B lives within the main_space_id from table A and therefore creates a situation where I am double counting.
I only want to count the trues for a distinct Main_space ID

**Current Data Model**

[image]

**Desired Output:**

[image]

From the above screenshot, I am trying to get a count of true values without double counting in the case for tableA_MAIN_SPACE_ID.

As you can see, each row is counted for true values as it relates to the subspace_ID (table B) for totals of 12 and 8 (1 if True, 0 if False) and for tableA, I am only counting distinct values so we only count Trues for a single MainspaceID and avoid recounting them.

If someone can advise on how to get this output from my current data model that would be very helpful!

My attempt as follows double counts trues for the Main space ID column..

```
SELECT 
       count(CASE WHEN B.TRIGGER_ON THEN 1 END)      as TRIGGER_ON,
       count(CASE WHEN B.DOCX_ON THEN 1 END)              as DOCX_ON,
       count(CASE WHEN A.GUEST_ON THEN 1 END)                 as SPRINTS,
       count(CASE WHEN A.USER_CONTROLS THEN 1 END)                 as SPRINTS
FROM DataModel
```

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <unique identifier> END)`?

Comment: @MatBailie thanks for the feedback! The only problem here is that if I use the Distinct Case option, it only counted a single instance of a true for all my TableA Main_Space_IDs

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.Guest_ON  THEN 1 END) as GuestON gave me a 1 for all the different Main_Space_IDs. If i have 500 in total, I would expect something like 300sh Trues for a distinct Main_Space ID

Comment: if you need to use this kind of query then you would also need a ranking function based on `Main_Space_IDs`  then add to the condition rank=1

Comment: Would be so much more useful if you supplied data in a reusable form and not as an image, it's easy to create fixed tables e.g. https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am trying to do is count all the True's for each tableB.Subspace_ID and the DISTINCT trues for tableA.Main_SPACE_ID.

You can use conditional aggregation.  In Snowflake, you can use the convenient `COUNT_IF()` for the first two columns.  However, for the second two, you need `COUNT(DISTINCT)` with conditional logic:

```
SELECT COUNT_IF( B.Trigger_on ) as Trigger_On,
       COUNT_IF( B. DOCX_ON ) as DOCX_ON,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN A.GUEST_ON THEN A.Main_SPACE_ID END) as GUEST_ON,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN A. USER_CONTROLS THEN A.Main_SPACE_ID END) as USER_CONTROLS
FROM tableA A JOIN
     tableB B
     ON B.Main_SPACE_ID = A.Main_SPACE_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Mabye:

```
SELECT 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN B.TRIGGER_ON THEN 1 END) AS TRIGGER_ON,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN B.DOCX_ON THEN 1 END) AS DOCX_ON,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT A.MAIN_SPACE_ID, A.GUEST_ON FROM DataModel WHERE A.GUEST_ON = TRUE) A) AS GUEST_ON
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT A.USER_CONTROLS, A.GUEST_ON FROM DataModel WHERE A.USER_CONTROLS = TRUE) A) AS USER_CONTROLS
FROM DataModel
```